# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'people.googlea' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql

WHAT IS A PROBLEM HERE ?

```
CREATE TABLE marks(
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
marks INT,
student_id INT
);


CREATE TABLE googlea(
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
student_name VARCHAR(20) ,
student_id INT ,
FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES marks(student_id)
);
```

Comment: Wrong direction. Have a fk from marks referencing googlea. Why two ID columns?

Comment: Usually foreign keys point to the primary key of the table. It's not required, but it's generally more appropriate.

Comment: Target column must be the leftmost or only column of an index. See duplicate topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below updated queries:

```
CREATE TABLE marks( 
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    marks INT, 
    student_id INT 
);

CREATE TABLE googlea( 
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    student_name VARCHAR(20) , 
    student_id INT , 
    FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES marks(id) 
);
```

Hope it works now.

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES marks(id)` Why would the id from googlea point to the id off marks.. Does not make sense in this case..

Comment: Please improve your code formatting. Write the queries neatly over multiple lines, then use Ctl-k to indent it so it's displayed ina code block.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in **FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES marks(student_id)**.
try this **FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES marks(id)**